# Run some code only after fetch statements inside of loops have finished executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch, use-effect

I am building an object out of two different requests from an API. There are three different `ids` used for those requests at any given time. e.g. `const ids = [1, 2, 3]`

The whole code is inside of a useEffect, as I would like it to run every time the `ids` change. Not sure whether this affects or not the code execution order.

I would like my program to behave in this order:

- Firstly, I would like to run requests to get 'general_info' for each ID and add them to an object.
- Secondly, I would like to run requests that compare each id to the remaining ids individually and add this info to the object.
- Thirdly, I would like to run some code ONLY AFTER the above code has finished 'merging into' this object. It's where I'm using React's UseState hook to set the objCopy as an object that will be displayed!

I appreciate this should deal with async requests, and some types of loops don't seem to be appropriate for this according to other posts. I am not sure whether to use `async await` or simply chain `then()` one after another.

Code is similar to this:

```
useEffect(() => {

  // ... some other code ...

  const obj = {}

  // 1st loop
  ids.forEach(id =>{
     fetch(`api/general_info?id=${id}`)
     //whatever comes as response, merge into 'obj' 
  })

  // 2nd loop (to be run only after first loop has finished merging into obj)
  idsToCompare = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]] // 

  idsToCompare.forEach(([id1, id2]) =>{
     fetch(`api/compare/?id1=${id1}&id2=${id2}`)
     //whatever comes as response, merge into 'obj' 
  })

  // 3 run this code ONLY AFTER the above loops have finished executing
  // (and obj merge is complete)!
  setCompleteObjToDisplay(obj) // React's setState
  console.log(obj) // complete obj!

}, [ids]) //every time ids change, this code should run.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to use async code with foreach. You could use `for in` instead and add async before the outer function

```js
useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  let obj = {} 

  for(const id in ids) {
    const res = await fetch(...)
    obj = {...obj, res}
  }

  idsToCompare = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]

  for(const [id1, id2] in idsToCompare) {
    const res = await fetch(...)
    obj = {...obj, res}
  }

  setCompleteObjToDisplay(obj) // I don't know if this function is asynchronous. Is so, add an await statement
  console.log(obj)
})(), [dependencies])
```

Comment: say I have more code before those loops, should they go inside of the async anonymous function? |||| regarding your comment --> the last function is not async, it's just a React set statement

Comment: You can put the code before the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
Using a IIFE is just a small trick to be able to use await

Comment: and the 'setCompleteObjToDisplay' MUST remain inside of the IIFE so that's executed in order?

Comment: You should put async before the outer function. I made a mistake, there's no need to use an async IIFE. If the outer function is async, you can use await without wrapping your code in a IIFE. The code will be executed from top to bottom, given that you put await before each asynchronous call

Comment: what do you mean by outer function? I have no 'async' word in my code.

Comment: So with useEffect, just use the IIFE. If you're not sure what to put in the IIFE, put everything inside it for now. The code will be executed from top to bottom. I advise you to learn about asynchronous calls and promises thought. It will slow you down a lot if you don't understand the basics. I've updated my answer with useEffect

Comment: Sorry I forgot the const. It should work with const

Answer (score 1):

Hugh's answer is the best solution, but I will add another information:

Another way to do it would be using Promises returns to control the main flow.

```js
(async function() {

    const obj = {}

   await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        // 1st loop
        ids.forEach(async (id) => {
            let data = await fetch(`api/general_info?id=${id}`)
            //whatever comes as response, merge into 'obj' 
            resolve(data);
        })
    })

    // 2nd loop (to be run only after first loop has finished merging into obj)
    idsToCompare = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]] // 

    await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        idsToCompare.forEach(([id1, id2]) =>{
            let data = await fetch(`api/compare/?id1=${id1}&id2=${id2}`)
            resolve(data);
            //whatever comes as response, merge into 'obj' 
        })
    })

    // 3 run this code ONLY AFTER the above loops have finished executing
    // (and obj merge is complete)!
    setCompleteObjToDisplay(obj)
    console.log(obj) // complete obj!

})();
```

This example is not the most elegant way to use Promises, but it serves well to show how they work =)